# Microsoft word 2007: how to number some pages in roman numerals and the rest in regular numbers

Tags: microsoft-word, page-numbers

If I have a 4 page word document, how can i number the first two as pages i, ii and the rest as 1,2,3,4 etc. 
[image: example]

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

START ON THE PAGE WHERE YOU WISH TO BEGIN THE ROMAN NUMERALS

1. Click the Insert tab on the Ribbon.
   The Insert tab is the second tab from the left and is located between the Home and Page Layout tabs.
2. In the Header & Footer area, choose Page Number→Format Page Numbers.
   The Format Page Numbers option is the second option from the bottom in the drop-down list.
   [image: Format page Numbers]
3. Choose the new numbering format:

[image: Page number format]

4 Click the Start At radio button and type the beginning page number in the box.
This is based on your personal preference. Type where you want the page numbers to begin.

5 Click OK to close the Page Number Format dialog box.
Word starts numbering your document at the specified page number

Answer (score 1):

Press Insert on the ribbon -> Breaks -> Section break (new page) where you want numbering style to differ from the previous pages.

Next click the cursor on the previous pages and Insert -> Page Number -> Format Page Number and choose the Number style from the drop down. Press Ok. Then place the cursor in the pages after the section break you created and repeat the above steps but this time with the different number style.

Comment: Not working, it seems to use the same number style on all pages even after page break

Comment: @Dr Deo, make sure you are inserting a new page section break and not just a page break.